# Turn off displays when inactive even when connected to AirPlay

Tags: macos, display, airplay

I've extended display to my LG OLED TV via AirPlay. In macOS 12.6.2 system preferences, I've set to turn off display when inactive for 1 minute. But when connected to AirPlay, the displays won't go off when inactive. Being it the OLED I'm afraid of pixel burn.

How to turn off displays when inactive even when extending display with AirPlay?